# How is the AuthorizedKeysCommand used in SSH?

Tags: ssh, centos7

I want to use the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` as a test on my server.
Steps:
1. Added the line `AuthorizedKeysCommand /etc/ssh/myScript.sh` to the end of the file.
2. Created a script `myScript.sh` in the `/etc/ssh/` location that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "Hello world";
```

This script has permissions 755 and is owned by root with group set to sshd.

3. Tried to restart the `SSHD` daemon by running: `sudo systemctl restart sshd`

`sshd` does not restart and exits. The error code too is not clear and does not go away until the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` is removed.

Where am I going wrong?

I am running SSH version: `OpenSSH_6.6.1p1  OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013` on a `Centos7` server.

Comment: What is the error message you get when you restart `sshd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, an [error message would be useful](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before), but I take a wild guess and maybe this happened:

```
systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
sshd[23748]: AuthorizedKeysCommand set without AuthorizedKeysCommandUser
systemd[1]: ssh.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
```

You need to the set the `AuthorizedKeysCommandUser` parameter as well, otherwise [sshd fails to start](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2287). Also, make sure to heed all the other requirements for `AuthorizedKeysCommand` laid out in [sshd_config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5), e.g. the script needs to be executable too.